# Physical only checkdb is failing, but full one is completed successfully

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, dbcc-checkdb

I am executing checkdb with physical_only option and it fails with multiple errors like below:

> **Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Line 1** 
> **Table error:** Object ID 1557580587,
>   index ID 1, partition ID 72057594088456192, alloc unit ID
>   72057594177454080 (type In-row data). The off-row data node at page
>   (1:13282192), slot 3, text ID 6370769698816 is referenced by page
>   (0:0), slot 0, but was not seen in the scan. 
> **Msg 8965, Level 16, State
>   1, Line 1** 
> **Table error:** Object ID 1557580587, index ID 1, partition ID
>   72057594088456192, alloc unit ID 72057594177454080 (type In-row data).
>   The off-row data node at page (1:13282192), slot 5, text ID
>   6370769764352 is referenced by page (0:0), slot 0, but was not seen in
>   the scan.
>  **CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 5255 consistency
>   errors in table 'TableX'** (object ID
>   1557580587). 
> **CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 5255 consistency
>   errors in database 'DatabaseX'**. repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum
>   repair level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB (DWH_LAND).

However full checkdb is successfull:

> **CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database
>   'DatabaseX'.** DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages,
>   contact your system administrator.

TableX has around 200 000 rows and has clustered columnstore index on it.

 We are using following version of SQL Server:

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU13) (KB4466404) - 14.0.3048.4


Should I be worried?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this a defect in SQL Server 2017 up to CU14. There was a similar issue with [nonclustered columnstore indexes in SQL Server 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3174088/fix-error-5283-when-you-run-dbcc-checkdb-on-a-database-that-contains-n).

It's detailed in this video: [CHECKDB Bug With SQL Server 2017 And ColumnStore Indexes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1a2vho7vdHw)

A more portable repro of the issue is this:

```
SELECT *, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), m.text + m.text + m.text + m.text + m.text) AS texty
INTO dbo.corrupt
FROM sys.messages AS m;

CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX cx_corrupt ON dbo.corrupt;

DBCC CHECKDB WITH PHYSICAL_ONLY;

DROP TABLE dbo.corrupt;
```